# Locally deploying Glass Java starter project, AuthFilter ClassNotFoundException

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I've followed the steps in the Java Quick Start to the letter.  When trying to deploy locally, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:14 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/derek/dev/external/git/mirror-quickstart-java/web/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:14 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /home/derek/dev/external/git/mirror-quickstart-java/web/WEB-INF/web.xml
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:14 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.glassware.AuthFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:339)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:274)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed authFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.glassware.AuthFilter
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@4c29d65b{/,/home/derek/dev/external/git/mirror-quickstart-java/web}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.glassware.AuthFilter
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:339)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:274)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8080
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: Server default is running at http://localhost:8080/
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin
Jun 6, 2013 9:53:15 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?  I've copied over the appropriate values to `oauth.properties` and `appengine-web.xml`.

Some system information (Running Ubuntu)

> Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 03:44:56-0500)
>
> Java version: 1.6.0_27, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
>
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>
> OS name:"linux", version: "3.2.0-45-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

EDIT: Deploying the Python Quick Start is also not working.  Stacktrace:

```
Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~glasstaskme/1.367898216022107922/oauth/handler.py", line 78, in get
    creds = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
  File "lib/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/oauth2client/client.py", line 1283, in step2_exchange
    headers=headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1570, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1317, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "lib/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1286, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 500, in getresponse
    raise HTTPException(str(e))
HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

I've double-checked my client IDs, even generating new ones and deleting the old ones, and everything seems to be in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Java quickstart project, be sure to do a mvn compile first:

```
mvn compile
```

Then, run it:

```
dev_appserver.sh ./web/
```

The quickstart instructions omit the compile step, so following them to the letter will get you in trouble :)

Comment: Goodness, that's a pretty rough step to omit from the quick start.  That worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: Make sure this gets filed as a documentation bug